# Drowning or something else?

Tags: word-request

If you kill someone by submerging their head in water, do you call it killing by *drowning* or something else?

Comment: It's simply "drown", a transitive verb. You are drowning them. You have drowned them.

Comment: And they have drowned, @JackO'Flaherty. _Drown_ can be transitive or intransitive.

Comment: @ColinFine  I know; I was just answering with respect to "If you kill someone...".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's drowning. There can be accidental drownings and there can be deliberate drownings.

If you're planning to kill someone this way, what you call it is probably not the biggest issue. :-)